# Wrong values after using forEach in Arraylist

Tags: java, loops, foreach

I`m doing the freecodecamp beginner tutorial and I have a problem with forEach function in Arraylist.
Following Code

```
number1.forEach(number -> {
      number1.set(number1.indexOf(number), number * 2);
      
    });
    System.out.println(number1);
```

The values are [2, 4, 11, 12] so I would expect to get [4, 8, 22, 24] but instead I get [8, 4, 22, 24]

Any Ideas what`s wrong?

As stated above.
I tried to check with indexOf if the values and indexes aren`t switched, because I used Sort function earlier, but they seem to be ok.
Other than that, everything went smooth and easy. IDK

Comment: what do you expect `number1.indexOf(number)` to return?

Comment: When the code is processing the first value (2) it sets the value at index 0 to 2 * 2, (i.e. 4) (number1 now contains [4, 4, 22, 24]).  When it processes the next value (4), it uses `indexOf` to find which index holds 4.  That is now also index 0, so it sets that to 2 * 4 (i.e 8).  This sort of behavior is why you should never modify an array while iterating over that array

Comment: @tibrogargan   It seems to be the Issue, Thank You.
I tried to change the value from 2 to 7 so that there are no 2 the same values after * 2   and it seems to work.
The tutorial uses .toString  with print instead of just print - does that have an influence or it wouldn`t work anyway?

Comment: It has no influence.  `println` internally uses `toString` anyway.  This is an inherent issue with modifying a collection during iteration, it's an antipattern  (Sometimes called "Iterate and Mutate").  If you need to do something like this, put the results into a second collection instead.

Comment: Thank You, that solves everything :) 
Now I`m just surprised that the tutorial showed it this way (iterating) and that it usezs toString if it`s internally used by println anyway.
I can`t upvote yet, sorry.

Comment: Using wrong with using `toString` like that.  Sometimes there can be subtle complications that can be avoided by doing this.  But yeah, teaching people using mutation during iteration is not good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with `[2, 4, 11, 12]`

During the first iteration, `number = 2`

You then call `number1.set(number1.indexOf(2), 2 * 2)`

We now have `[4, 4, 11, 12]`

During the second iteration, `number = 4`

Once again, we call `number1.set(number1.indexOf(4), 4 * 2)`

Here is the problem: **indexOf returns the index of the first instance of that value!**

So, `number1.indexOf(4) = 0`, so it places `8` into index `0` instead of index `1`

As @Tibrogargan mentioned in the comments, this is a prime example of why you shouldn't modify an array while iterating across it

Your code for `number1` will not work whenever there exists a number `Y` in `number1` such that there exists a number `X` where `Y = 2X`

Comment: Thank You, that solves everything (just as previous comment) :) Now Im just surprised that the tutorial showed it this way (iterating) and that it usezs toString if its internally used by println anyway. Maybe I missed something.